# Error in routing in angular1

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am getting error in routing to about page. Home page is loading successfully. I am new to angular. Please help me to do it successfully.
here is the code link

`enter code here` [Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/mylft7tP6Kwgm4Jd6h71?p=preview)

find code here 
**index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 

  <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-bootstrap/0.5pre/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    </head>
    <body ng-app="demo">
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>


    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**Js**

// Code goes here

```
var app = angular.module("demo", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        }).
        when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: 'partials/404.html'
        });
    }
]);

app.controller('mainController', function() {});

app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $http, $location){
 $scope.login= function() {

        $location.path("/home");


    }
});

app.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.about= function() {

        $location.path("/about");


    }
});
```

Comment: Didn't you see an alert when you only post a Plunker link saying you to **post your code in your question as well**? It is not here to be bypassed with `enter code here`.

Comment: I thought it will work. Now find code in question.

Comment: What *exactly* are you getting as an error? Saying "getting error in routing to about page" is not a sufficient description of a problem. What is happening that you are not expecting? What error message in the console? What is supposed to happen? Please [edit] your question to include this information. Please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [ask], and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Correct your references as `<script src="main.js"></script>` and create `partial/home.html`. It will work then.

Try to utilize browser developer tool (F12), it will you help to find actual error.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your plunker.

1. You don't have the partials created in your plunker version. You need to create the files partials/about.html and partials/home.html.
2. The css/main.css. You have created a style.css in the root folder, but referred css/main.css in index.html.
   3.The path to main.js was wrong. The file is in the root folder and you referred it as js/main.js. Please refer it as `<script src="main.js"></script>`
3. You have to call the routes from the partials.
4. You have created the about method in aboutController. But, it should be in the home controller. About controller will only be instantiated when you route to the about.html page.
5. You have referred an URL '/home' which is not defined in the main.js.

Please find the following working plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/APKWvpuTfivua5CovRp7?p=preview

```
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module("demo", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        }).
        when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        }).
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: 'partials/404.html'
        });
    }
]);


app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $http, $location){
 $scope.login= function() {
        $location.path("/login");

    }
    $scope.about= function() {
        $location.path("/about");

    }
});

app.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.backToHome = function() {
     window.history.back();
    }
});
app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.backToHome = function() {
     window.history.back();
    }
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-bootstrap/0.5pre/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body ng-app="demo">
<div ng-view></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Yes. I have edited the answer with proper explanation.  Hope that helps.